# Is there a way to access individual header parameters from the body of a response in Java?

Tags: java, spotify

I am new to coding with APIs and am not very experienced otherwise so I apologize if I get any terminology wrong.

I was wondering if there is a way to access only the value for a header without having to parse through the whole response as a string? Is there a method where I can pass the header and receive the value associated to it if there is a header with that title already in the java.net package?

The goal would be to save the access token in a string variable so that it could be used for other API calls that require it.

Here's my code;

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        .uri(URI.create("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"))
        .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        .method("POST", HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString("grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=[MY_ID]&client_secret=[MY_SECRET]"))
        .build();
    HttpResponse<String> response = HttpClient.newHttpClient().send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    System.out.println(response.body());
}
```

And I get this;

```
{"access_token":"[ACCESS_TOKEN]","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600}
```

I just want to save [ACCESS_TOKEN] into a string variable. Thanks!

Comment: *"I apologize if I get any terminology wrong."*  ... Ermm headers are not in the body.   You are not talking about headers.  You are talking about attributes of some JSON sent as the response body.  If you learn and use the correct terminology, it is easier to understand you ... and you are more likely to be able to find the solution for yourself. In this case, the solution is to use a JSON parser library to parse the JSON in the body.  That will give you an in-memory object and you can call a method on that object to "get" the value of the attribute.

Comment: In short: learn the terminology *first* by reading about the technology that you are trying to use.  It will save you time.   (P.S. I am teaching ... not criticizing.)

Answer (score 0):

That response **is not a header**. Headers are something else. Here, the spotify API server is no doubt responding with headers like `Content-Type` (and its value would be `application/json; charset=UTF-8`).

What you're looking at **is** the body. It would be kinda silly if calling `.body()` returns the thing that is the opposite of the body.

That body is in a format called JSON. You need a JSON parser to parse it. I suggest [Jackson JSON](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson).

Comment: I was under the impression that the body is made up of various headers, and I thought that "access_token" was one of them. In this case, I was under the impression that the body was "access_token", "token-type", and "expires_in"; do I have that wrong?

I will look into Jackson JSON, though, thank you!

Comment: The term 'header' has a very specific meaning in HTML land. These aren't headers. Parameter is something else too. These aren't parameters. The body consists of JSON and the JSON contains key and value pairs. 'header' as a word doesn't apply to JSON. I don't know what you're thinking, but either you're misunderstanding, or you are using words that mean wildly different things than what you think they mean.

Comment: Oh, got it! So "access_token" is a key and "[ACCESS_TOKEN]" would be its value, and they make up the JSON, which make up the body. Those are the things I had wrong, I think. Thank you!

Comment: You got it now :)

Answer (score 0):

You have the JSON string you need, now you can use JSON the get the information you want. The runnable demo console application below utilizes the **[json-20210307.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/json/json/20210307/)** library which you will need to apply.

Be sure to read the extensive comments in code so to see what is going on. You can remove the comments later if you like.

Important methods within the demo code below are the `getJsonKeys()` method and the `getJsonKeyValue()` method:

```
/*
    Dependencies (libraries): json-20210307.jar
        You can download this JAR file from here:
            https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/json/json/20210307/
        or download directly from here:
            https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/json/json/20210307/json-20210307.jar

        Add this library to your project.
 */
package getobjectfromjsonstringdemo;

public class GetObjectFromJsonStringDemo {
    
    // Class Member Variables:
    public final String LS = System.lineSeparator();
    
    /* Open a Keyboard Input Stream. 'Don't close' this Stream! 
       If you do, you will have restart the application in order 
       to utilize it again. The JVM will automatically close this 
       resource when the application ends. Never close it unless
       you are absolutely sure you will not need it again for the 
       current run life of your app.              */
    public final java.util.Scanner userInput = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    
    
    // Application entry point:
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* App started this way to avoid the need for statics 
           (unless we want them):        */
        new GetObjectFromJsonStringDemo().startApp(args);
    }
    
    /** 
     * Alternate application entry point - called from the 'main()' method: 
     * 
     * @param args (Optional - String VarArgs) If there are going to be 
     * command-line arguments, they would be supplied from the 'main()'
     * method. Doing the method parameter this way allows us to call this 
     * method without any arguments at all. This is done for the sake of 
     * this demo so that another 'while' loop didn't need to be used to 
     * continuously redisplay the menu after the "Press Enter to Continue" 
     * prompt. 
     */   
    private void startApp(String... args) {
        // The JSON String:  {"access_token":"[ACCESS_TOKEN]","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600}
        String json = "{\"access_token\":\"[ACCESS_TOKEN]\",\"token_type\":\"Bearer\",\"expires_in\":3600}";
        System.out.println("The Supplied JSON String:" + LS + "------------------------");
        System.out.println(json + LS);
        
        // Get the Keys from the JSON String:
        String[] keys = getJsonKeys(json);
        
        // Build The Menu To select any one of the acquired Keys so to get its value:
        // ==========================================================================
        // User Prompt menu input varaible initialized to empty (null string):
        String choice = "";
        int finalI = keys.length + 1; // Will hold the last item number in Menu for 'Quit':
        
        // Keep looping while 'choice' is empty:
        while (choice.isEmpty()) {
            // Prompt string:
            System.out.println("Select the Key Name you would like the Value for:");
            
            // Loop through the 'keys[]' array and build into menu:            
            for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("  " + (i + 1) + ") " + keys[i]);
            }
            // Menu separator so to apply the 'Quit' menu item beneath it:
            System.out.println("  -------------------------");
            System.out.println("  " + finalI + ") Quit This Application!");
            System.out.print("Your Choice? -> ");
            
            /* Get User Input and trim it so to remove any possible
               leading or trailing whitespaces:      */
            choice = userInput.nextLine().trim();
            
            // Entry Validation:
            /* Make sure the entry is an integer numerical value. If it
               is then make sure the numercal value entered is within 
               the range of the number of menu item (however number of 
               menu items there actually are):            */
            if (!choice.matches("\\d+") || Integer.parseInt(choice) < 1 || 
                                           Integer.parseInt(choice) > finalI) {
                // If input validation fails then inform User and repropmt:
                System.out.println("Invalid Menu Choice! (" + choice + ") Try Again..." + LS);
                choice = ""; // Empty 'choice' to ensure reprompt:
            }
        }
        
        /* If we make it to this point then validation was successful 
           so convert the menu item number to an int type variable. 
           This value will be used as an index number (minus 1) to get 
           the related Key Name from the 'keys[]' string array:   */
        int choiceVal = Integer.parseInt(choice);
        
        // Has QUIT been selected (the last menu item)?
        if (choiceVal == finalI) {
            System.out.println(LS + "Quitting - Bye Bye" + LS);
            // Effectively exit this method which will ultimately end the application:
            return; 
        }
        
        /* No...Quit hasn't been selected so let's get and 
           display the selected Key Value:        */
        Object keyValue = getJsonKeyValue(json, keys[choiceVal - 1]);
        System.out.println(LS + "Value for the Key: \"" + keys[choiceVal - 1] 
                           + "\" is: -> " + keyValue.toString() + LS);
        pressEnterToContinue();
    }
    
    /* A prompt to allow User to continue and disply the menu again.
       (a million and a half ways to do this sort of thing)    */
    private void pressEnterToContinue() {
        // Prompt...
        String entry = "";
        while (entry.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("<< Press ENTER To Continue >>");
            System.out.println("<<     Enter q to Quit     >>");
            entry = userInput.nextLine().trim();
            // Validate...
            /* If the entry isn't empty (which an ENTER Key Hit 
               will do) and the entry wasn't a 'Q' in any letter 
               case then the entry is Invalid to continue the demo 
               so, ask again.            */
            if (!entry.isEmpty() && !entry.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
                System.out.println("Invalid Entry! (" + entry + ") - Try Again..." + LS);
                entry = ""; // Empty so to ensure re-loop.
                continue;
            }
            
            // If we make it to this point then, validation is successful:
            if (!entry.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
                // Make 'entry' contain something relative so not to re-loop:
                entry = "continueON";
            }
            // Otherwise....QUIT.
            else {
                System.out.println("Quitting - Bye Bye" + LS);
                System.exit(0);
            }
           
        }
        
        /* Call the startApp() method again but with no arguments
           so to display the menu again:        */
        startApp();
    }

    /**
     * This method retrieves the Key Names within a JSON String and returns them
     * within a String[] array.<br>
     *
     * @param jsonString (String) The JSON String to work on.<br>
     * 
     * @param parentNodeName (Optional - String VarArg) A lot of times Keys and 
     * their respective values are nested within sever specific parent nodes. 
     * This parameter allows you to specify the parent node from where to acquire 
     * the desired Key names.
     * <p>
     * If there are parent nodes within the JSON string and you supply nothing 
     * to this parameter then, the outer most Parent Key names will be returned.
     *<p>
     * @return (String[] Array) A String array of Key names contained within the
     *         supplied JSON String.
     */
    public String[] getJsonKeys(String jsonString, String... parentNodeName) {
        String parentNode = "";
        if (parentNodeName.length > 0 && !parentNodeName[0].trim().isEmpty()) {
               parentNode = parentNodeName[0];
        }
        
        org.json.JSONObject obj = new org.json.JSONObject(jsonString);
        if (!parentNode.isEmpty()) {
            org.json.JSONObject parentObj = obj.getJSONObject(parentNode);
            java.util.Set<String> keyNames = parentObj.keySet();
            return keyNames.toArray(new String[0]);
        }
        else {
            java.util.Set<String> keyNames = obj.keySet();
            return keyNames.toArray(new String[0]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method retrieves the Key Value for the supplied Key Name contained
     * within the supplied JSON String.
     * 
     * @param jsonString (String) The JSON String to work on.<br>
     * 
     * @param keyName (String) The Key Name to get the related Value for.<br>
     * 
     * @return (Object) The Value related to the supplied Key Name. You will 
     * need to cast the returned object to the desired data type the key value 
     * is meant to be or use the 'toString()' method.
     */
    public Object getJsonKeyValue(String jsonString, String keyName) {
        org.json.JSONObject obj = new org.json.JSONObject(jsonString);
        Object keyValue = obj.get(keyName);
        return keyValue;
    }
    // DONE.
}
```